# Understanding of JavaScript Prototypes

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I play with following JS code. And I have 2 questions.

1) Why User is not prototype of  author_1?

2) Why after the resetting of Author.prototype author_1 becomes not an instanceof Author?

```
function User(_fname){
    this.fname = _fname;
    return this;
}

function Author(){
    this.book = "Magick of JS";
    return this;
}

Author.prototype = new User('John');
author_1 = new Author;

console.log("=======================");
console.log(author_1 instanceof Author);      // true
console.log(author_1 instanceof User);        // true
console.log(User.isPrototypeOf(author_1));    // false (>>>> 1) WHY? <<<<)
console.log(author_1.constructor);            // User(_fname)
console.log(author_1.__proto__);              // User { fname="John"} 
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(author_1)); // User { fname="John"}
console.log(author_1.constructor.prototype);  // User {}

Author.prototype = new User('Alex');
author_2 = new Author;

console.log("=======================");
console.log(author_1 instanceof Author);      // false  (>>>> 2) WHY? <<<<)
console.log(author_1 instanceof User);        // true
console.log(User.isPrototypeOf(author_1));    // false
console.log(author_1.constructor);            // User(_fname)
console.log(author_1.__proto__);              // User { fname="John"} 
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(author_1)); // User { fname="John"}
console.log(author_1.constructor.prototype);  // User {}

console.log("=======================");
console.log(author_2 instanceof Author);      // true
console.log(author_2 instanceof User);        // true
console.log(User.isPrototypeOf(author_2));    // false
console.log(author_2.constructor);            // User(_fname)
console.log(author_2.__proto__);              // User { fname="Alex"}
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(author_2)); // User { fname="John"}
console.log(author_2.constructor.prototype);  // User {}

console.log("=======================");
console.log(author_1); // User {book: "Magick of JS", fname: "John"}
console.log(author_2); // User {book: "Magick of JS", fname: "Alex"}
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Thanks for help! But now I can't understand how author_1 can know that it's an Author

```
function log(){ console.log.apply(console, arguments) }

function User(_fname){
    this.fname = _fname;
    return this;
}

function Author(){
    this.book = "Magick of JS";
    return this;
}

Author.prototype = new User('John');
author_1 = new Author;

log(author_1);              // User { book="Magick of JS", fname="John"}
log(author_1.__proto__);    // User { fname="John"}
log(author_1.constructor);  // User(_fname)

log(author_1 instanceof Author); // true

// How author_1 kowns that it's an Author? Where is property?
// Can I find it in web inspector? Or it's hidden value?
```

Comment: Don't you need `()` after `new Author` for both author_1 and author_2?  That may vastly change your results.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein no, you don't. It's optional. `new ConstructorFunction` behaves exactly the same as `new ConstructorFunction()`. It's just less common syntax.

Comment: OP, why are you doing `return this` inside the functions acting like constructors?

Comment: By default any constructor function makes *return this*, I just do it visibly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The object "User" is the constructor function. Each **instance** of "User" is a different object. Hence, `User.isPrototypeOf(author_1)` is `false` because the object "User" is simply not the prototype; that instance you created is the prototype.
2. When you change the prototype, the object previously created retains its original prototype chain, and hence it appears to the runtime system not to be an instance of "Author" anymore.

Comment: I've started to write the answer, but I can add to this one as well:
1) you can also take a look https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf for the usage of isPrototypeOf

Comment: +1. Inheritance in JavaScript is between objects and not classes. There is  no _real_ (atm) notion of classes in the language and typing is behavioral (and stronger in a sense). `User` is just a function that is used as a template for your objects, it's not a class.

Comment: Thanks. There are also several extremely clear and thorough answers on Stackoverflow by T.J. Crowder that give a great guide to this stuff, and really solid coding approaches too.

Answer (score 3):

1) 
The new operator acts like this:

```
var x = new F()
// approximately the same as this:
x = Object.create(F.prototype); // x inherits from the prototype of F
F.call(x); // F is called with x as 'this'
```

For this reason:

```
User.isPrototypeOf(author_1) // false because 
User.prototype.isPrototypeOf(author_1) // true
```

Resources:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

2) 
Instanceof acts like this:

```
x instanceof F
// aproximately the same as this:
Object.getPrototypeOf(x) === F.prototype
```

When you do `F.prototype = {}`, you changed the property of F, but you didn't change the prototype chain of the already created object `x`.

```
var initialProto = {id:1};
F.prototype = initialProto;
var x = new F();

var anotherProto = {id:2};
F.prototype = anotherProto ;

Object.getPrototypeOf(x) === initialProto // true;
initialProto === anotherProto // obviously false
```

Resources:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof